# jQuery: button to be pressed exactly X times

Tags: jquery, button, experimental-design

I am working on an experimental task which requires the button to be pressed exactly X times. The idea is that person needs to press it, for example, 4 times in a row (max 0.5s interval among presses). For now in my code every click increases variable "click" by 1 and once it equals to the selected number (4), the player receives a "green signal".

Is there a way to make sure that if a person clicks button 5 or more times in a row, the function is not executed? So that I would constrict player to press button **exactly** 4 times.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-circle main_button"></button>

var click = 0

$('.main_button').on('click',function(){
    click = click + 1;
});

$('.main_button').dblclick(function(){
    click = click + 1;
});

$('.main_button').on('click',function() {
    if (click == 4) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.feedback_g').addClass("bg-success");
            }, 500);
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button after 4 presses - add

```
$('.main_buton').prop("disabled",true);
```

Full code:

```
var click = 0

$('.main_button').on('click',function(){
    click = click + 1;
});

$('.main_button').dblclick(function(){
    click = click + 1;
});

$('.main_button').on('click',function() {
    if (click == 4) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.feedback_g').addClass("bg-success");
            }, 500);
        $('.main_buton').prop("disabled",true);
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there also a way to make sure that if people click 5 times, my click function is not executed? Even if I disable button after 4 clicks, the function to add class will work. It would be perfect if this function would work only if people pressed button exactly 4 times with max 0.5s interval between clicks

Comment: They won't be able to click 5 times because the button is disabled after 4 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Need to be improved, but something like this could work :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark rounded-circle main_button"></button>

<script>
    var click = 0

    $('.main_button').on('click',function(){
       updateNb();
    });

    $('.main_button').dblclick(function(){
        updateNb(); 
    });

    $('.main_button').on('click',function() {
        if (click == 4) {
            setTimeout(function() {
             if (click == 4) {
                $('.feedback_g').addClass("bg-success");
            }

            click = 0;


                }, 500);
            };
        });


    function updateNb(){
        if(click > 4){
            click = 0;
        }
        click++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! But in this case if I click button e.g. 6 times, after 4 clicks my function (addClass) still gets executed. Is there any way to make sure that if I click continuously on the button for more than 4 times, function will not work? I want to prevent people from randomly clicking non-stop on the button (in this case they would need to press button exactly 4 times and wait 0.5s without pressing anything).

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. Actually it stops people from pressing the button non-stop. Thank you!